# Directory not writable according to access(), user still able to create files in it

Tags: c, libc, rlwrap

I received a [bug report](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/90)
that has me scratching my head.  In my program, I test the
writability of a directory (which is the user's home directory by
default) before having `readline` collect history and write it to a file in that directory at program exit.

Here is the problematic code:

```
if (access(dirname, W_OK) != 0)
  complain("cannot create %s in %s", filename, dirname, errno);
else {
  use_readline_for_stuff();
  write_history("%s/%s", dirname, filename);
  exit(0);
}
```

(This is pseudo-C, of course. The real code is [here](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/8fd1b6b84529b11ba99eb471b2a780666446ffe9/src/main.c#L614-L623))

The user (let's call her `USER`) reports getting an error message "cannot create xxx in
/home/USER: permission denied", that disappears after manually creating the file with `USER@host > touch /home/USER/xxx`.

I would expect an unwritable home directory to lead to all kind of
problems, but the user can even  simply `touch` a file in that directory.

The program doesn't run suid, USER owns her home directory (and
clearly can create files in it). My program is apparently the only
program that displays this kind of problem. It has been fairly widely used
for years, and this is the first time this bug gets reported

The Linux manpage for `access (2)` says

> if a directory is found to be writable, it probably  means  that
>   files  can  be  created  in the directory

Why *probably*? Why (and when) not *always* (apart from a race condition like someone changing permissions just after the `access()` call, full inode tables or hitting user limits) all of which don't seem to be the problem here - especially since the `access()` call fails, and `touch xxx` succeeds.

Comment: An ACL —  Access Control List?  Even if the user-group-other permissions say "user X as a member of group Y cannot create a file here", and ACL may override that.  Another possible problem could be an NFS auto-mounted home directory, though by the time someone's logged in, that usually is no longer a problem.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that also. But can an ACL make it impossible for my program to create a file, while still allowing `touch` to do the same?

Comment: Given that this is in the home directory of USER, it probably isn't an ACL issue.  It is surprising.  What diagnostics have you got available? Have you analyzed the permissions on `/`, `/home`, `/home/USER`? Have you double-checked the current permissions on the executable, as opposed to the ones you expect to be on it? If there is a SUID or SGID bit lurking around, `access()` can give the wrong answer. Is there a chance that the primary group of the user is Group1, but the home directory belongs to Group2? It shouldn't be an issue if `USER` owns their home directory, but that's why you check.

Comment: As you can tell, I have questions but no answer.  But I'm not sure that anyone can provide a useful answer with the information available as yet.  The issue is going to depend on the platform, the file system(s), the permissions on programs and directories.  Is there any chance you're looking in the wrong place?  You look in (potentially) different locations if someone uses `~/xxx` vs `~USER/xxx`. (On my work machine, `~jleffler` maps to `/u/jleffler` and `~` maps to `/work4/jleffler` — as required by POSIX when I set `HOME=/work4/jleffler`.)

Comment: Many of those questions have already been asked in the discussion [here](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/90). I'm still intrigued by the _probably_ in the manpage text. What is the author hinting at?

Comment: How are you creating the file? Where is that error message coming from, it does not seem to be standard?  `EACCES` can be raised for a number reasons, see `man open`.

Comment: I'm not creating any file yet. `access(homedir, W_OK)` returns -1, with `errno == EACCES`, while the user can touch any file in `homedir`. That is what I don't understand.

Comment: The *probably* could mean that the create file might still fail for other reasons, for example if the inode table is full.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought the creation was failing and the `access` working.  Check there is execute (search) access on all the directories in the path.

Comment: I note that the claimed output line `drwxr-xr-x  1 /home/REDACTED_USER              users 3.0K Sep 20 10:41 REDACTED_USER` is a very curious output from `ls`; the file name is in the wrong place, and the user/group are missing.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong.  I wonder if `/home` is a circuitous symlink?  But I'm still not sure whether that explains what is reported.  I also wonder why you get ENOENT rather than EACCES when you try to `access()` the files `/home/USER/.terminfo` and `/home/USER/.sqlhosts_plus` — I think I'd expect EACCES if the home directory isn't accessible as indicated by accessing that.  Very peculiar.

Comment: You could show us the strace-output for your process, this might shed some light on this (actually, the line with the access-call should suffice)

Comment: @Ctx: in the link [**`here`**](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/90) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749093/directory-not-writable-according-to-access-user-still-able-to-create-files-in?noredirect=1#comment92422903_52749093) to me, there is the `strace` output.

Comment: @Ctx: see the [bug report](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/90). The `strace` output doesn't give any more information than `access(homedir, W_OK)` failing with `errno == EACCES`

Comment: @HansLub ah, ok. Btw. the "probably" means, that it is filesystem dependent; on some filesystems, you really can open the directory like a file for writing

Comment: Near the top of the `strace` output, there's a successful open and read of `/etc/ld.so.cache`.  Is that normal?  Could that account for any of the trouble if it contains something abnormal?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler normal for linux, just speeds up finding the libraries for dynamic linking

Comment: @Ctx: Thanks; I wasn't sure — it could have been harmless (like not finding `/etc/ld.so.preload` is harmless, but finding it might not be), or not.  It was probably worth the check.

Comment: I'm completely out of ideas in the absence of the output from `ls -ld / /home /home/USER; ls -la /home/USER`.  It couldn't be something weird like there's a named (Unix-domain) socket `.sqlplus_history` or some other eccentric file type?  I still don't have any good, plausible ideas; this is clutching at straws, but I suspect you're close to that stage as well.  Is there any chance that some weird file system like AFS is in play?

Comment: @Jonathan: changing the history filename to something else doesn't make a difference (_except_ when specifying a different directory: creating the file in `/tmp` works just fine). I'm also out of ideas, that's why I post here. Thanks a lot for your suggestions anyway!!

Comment: The original poster at github seems to have "redacted" a lot of things. I suspect, that he introduced a inconsistency there.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the bug reporter whether their home directory is FUSE mounted. Of course, they might not know but someone probably does. It could well be a buggy or non-existent access implementation in the FUSEd virtual filesystem. But honestly, fix your code. Don't test before use; it's a bad idiom and it was bound to get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @rci: If I wouldn't test, `readline` would only try to create the history file (and fail) when the user closes the session. She might have appreciated the error message before typing in all those obscure commands and then losing them...

Comment: Wild guess: something like AppArmor/SELinux getting in the way? (`touch` being whitelisted, `rlwrap` not?)

Answer (score 1):

So, I know this is a 5 year old post, but as it doesn't have any answers. Since I found it while searching for the same problem, I thought I'd answer it with my own solution.

It's actually more of a workaround, because I don't know the cause. Similar to the OP, I had an NFS directory where calls to `access(2)` to test for write permission were failing. Write operations themselves were not failing, just `access(2)` tests.

Here is the test code I wrote to troubleshoot (run as `home_access_test` in the examples below).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        char *hd = getenv("HOME");
        if (argc > 1) {
                hd = argv[1];
        }

        int mode = W_OK;
        int r = 0;

        printf("checking if %s is writable.\n",hd);

        r =  access(hd,mode);
        if (r != 0) {
                perror(hd);
                printf("no.\n");
        } else {
                printf("yes.\n");
        }
}
```

Here is an example of the test code / problem.

```
jdimpson@magpi:~ $ ./home_access_test /home/jdimpson
checking if /home/jdimpson is writable.
/home/jdimpson: Permission denied
no.
jdimpson@magpi:~ $ ls -ld /home/jdimpson
drwxrwxr-x 60 jdimpson jdimpson 4096 Feb  3 23:01 /home/jdimpson
jdimpson@magpi:~ $ mkdir foo
jdimpson@magpi:~ $ ls -ld /home/jdimpson/foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 jdimpson jdimpson 4096 Feb  3 23:02 /home/jdimpson/foo
jdimpson@magpi:~ $ ./home_access_test /home/jdimpson/foo
checking if /home/jdimpson/foo is writable.
yes.
jdimpson@magpi:~ $
```

To reiterate what this example shows, there are no actual write failures; just permission denied reported by `access(2)`. This was a nuisance because I have a program that refuses to write to its config file because the directory that it is in is being tested using `access(2)`.

In brief, my environment was a Linux NFS server and Linux NFS client, using NFSv3 over UDP.

The "solution" that I stumbled across was simple. Here's the setup:

```
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ sudo chmod a+w .
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ls -ld . jdimpson/ phred/
drwxrwxrwx 20 root     root     4096 Feb  3 23:23 .
drwxrwxr-x 61 jdimpson jdimpson 4096 Feb  3 23:21 jdimpson/
drwx------  7 jdimpson jdimpson 4096 Feb  3 23:23 phred/
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/jdimpson
checking if /home/jdimpson is writable.
/home/jdimpson: Permission denied
no.
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/phred
checking if /home/phred is writable.
/home/phred: Permission denied
no.
```

Both these folder exhibit the problem. Then I moved one directory into the other, and back out again, which fixed that directory:

```
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ mv jdimpson/ phred
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/phred/jdimpson/
bash: /home/jdimpson/home_access_test: No such file or directory
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ /home/phred/jdimpson/home_access_test /home/phred/jdimpson
checking if /home/phred/jdimpson is writable.
yes.
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ mv phred/jdimpson/ .
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/jdimpson
checking if /home/jdimpson is writable.
yes.
```

And I repeated it for the other directory, which then fixed it as well:

```
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/phred/
checking if /home/phred/ is writable.
/home/phred/: Permission denied
no.
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ mv phred/ jdimpson/
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/jdimpson/phred
checking if /home/jdimpson/phred is writable.
yes.
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ mv jdimpson/phred/ .
jdimpson@magpi:/home $ ~/home_access_test /home/phred/
checking if /home/phred/ is writable.
yes.
sudo chmod go-w .
```

I don't know what the root cause was, and can only hypothesize that moving the folder into a sub-folder and then back out caused whatever meta-data that was incorrect to be fixed.

Not shown here, but running the script on the NFS server didn't exhibit the  problem, and nor did moving the directories around in a similar fashion on the NFS server fix anything. So I assume the problem was caused in part by being on an NFS share.

Comment: The [bug report](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/90) and the following discussion give a bit more context.  You are right: it was an NFS issue. Your fix is original, though a bit of a kludge, and my program (rlwrap) will not always have the permissions to move the directory it wants to write into (for that, it would need to have write permissions in the _parent_ of that directory)